# What is "this.somevariable" means in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I found some code like this:

```
Function a(){ this.somevariable = ''; }
```

And some other code like this:

```
Function a(){ var somevariable = ''; }
```

The difference between them is the variable declaration. I need to know what is the `this` from `this.somevariable`. Is it different from `var`?

Comment: If you want to learn more, instead of posting to SO every time you run in the next little question, where you will often get answers which are misleading or incomplete, you should do what every other person in the history of computing has done when learning a new language which is to read the documentations, the intros, the tutorials, and the blog posts. After all, if you were learning Italian, would you post to an Italian site every time you ran into a word you didn't know, or would you study an Italian textbook?

Comment: For future reference, there is no need to include in your question personal details such as your history of learning the language, or your personal desires. They are irrelevant and distracting. To be perfectly honest, nobody cares. There is also no need to leave "thank you" comments on answers. If an answer was helpful, then upvote it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`this` is a keyword in JavaScript.

```
function test(){
　　this.x = 10;     
}
```

in this case `this` represents the internal object, only can use in the function.

With the function of different occasions, `this`'s value will change. But there is a general principle: `this` means the object which invoke the function.

Case 1:
 pure function call:

This is the most common use of the function, belongs to the global call.
So `this` just means of the global object Global.

e.g:

```
function test(){
　　　　this.m = 10;
　　　　alert(this.m);
　　}
　　test(); // there alert 10
```

In order to prove `this` is a global object:

```
   var m = 10;
　　function test(){
　　　　alert(this.m);
　　}
　　test(); // 10
```

And:

```
   var m = 10;
　　function test(){
　　　　this.m = 0;
　　}
　　test();
　　alert(m); // 10
```

Case 2:
As the object which calls the function.

```
function test(){
　　　　alert(this.m);
　　}
　　var obj = {};
　　obj.m = 10;
　　obj.n = test;
　　obj.n(); // 10
```

Case 3:

As a constructor

```
function test(){
　　　　this.m = 10;
　　}
　　var obj = new test();
　　alert(obj.m); // 10
```

In order to show that `this` is not a global object in this case:

```
   var m = 10;
　　function test(){
　　　　this.m = 1;
　　}
　　var o = new test();
　　alert(m); //10
```

Comment: Ok thank sir @aircraft

Comment: Instead of writing the nine millionth description of `this` in JS, it would be much preferable to point the OP to an existing, comprehensive answer here on SO, or an authoritative web page such ashttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. You can do that in a comment, not an answer.